# How to format a string according to the formatting method entered by user in c++?

Tags: c++

How to format a string according to the formatting method  entered by user in c++?
For example, here is an integer:
`int x = 100;`
If a user inputs a formatting method (a string):
`"%x"`，
I want to output: `0x40`.

And another user inputs a formatting string:
`%.4f`,
I want it output:`100.0000`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the following two concepts:

1.

- read in the formatting string from the user
- reject anything with more than one format specifier
- reject anything with wrong format specifier for the type of the variable you want to output (using a float specifier for an integer for example would be wrong; just mentioning it specifically because your example looks like this....)
- reject anything with the wrong format specifier for the width of the variable (same as above, just another detail)
- reject wrong specifiers which do not attempt to output the variable (there are some fancy/dagerous things which could otherwise be done with a user-provided string...)
- remove anything but the format specifier (assuming you mean to not allow "decoration")
- either reject above by removing it and use the remainder
- or reject by giving an error message and asking for another input
- use the string for output

2. 

- provide user with a choice of predefined safe and applicable formatting options

For security and reliability reasons I would probably go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` accepts any string as its first argument, not just string literals. Just be careful that the format **must** match the arguments. That makes this rather error-prone. E.g. specifying `%d` and passing `char` is undefined behaviour.

```
int main(){
    std::string user_format = "%x";

    int x = 100;

    std::printf(user_format.c_str(),x);
}
```

`std::hex` and `std::setprecision` modifiers might be more suited for this task.

Comment: A little more modern formatting libraries like `{fmt}` or `std::format` are not suitable for this?

Comment: @MatG Yes, `std::format` AFAIK would solve this safely because it will cast the arguments to correct types, but only MSVC has support for it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::printf` is not safe to use with user defined strings however there are some c++ implementations which provide a type safe alternative with the same format strings:

- [boost format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)
- [fmtlib](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#printf-formatting)

There is also [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) but this doesn't use `printf` style format strings.

A fmtlib example would be:

```
std::string format;
std::cin >> format;
try
{
  fmt::printf(format, 100);
}
catch (std::exception&)
{
  std::cout << "invalid format string\n";
}
```